# Django what will happen if I use os.environ.__setitem__ to change DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE?

Tags: python, django

I want to change the location of django's settings.py file. But I don't find anyone do this by using `__setitem__`. I use this to configure settings successfully,but I want to know , is there some bad consequences ?

Comment: Why would you do this? What problem does it solve?

Comment: it helps change the location of the settings.py

Comment: You need to explain in more detail what you are doing. The little information you give here doesn't make much sense on its own.

Comment: You would be better either setting it in the shell, or in your manage.py